# Running hive query in Hive action Vs Beeline in Oozie

Tags: hive, beeline

I am running a hive query something like this(ignore the syntax if it is incorrect) in hive action in oozie
`Insert overwrite table partition(col=x)select * from table`
And I see the number of reducers are set to 1 in all the reducer stages and the query is taking too much time, but the same query when I ran through beeline using shell action in oozie, I can see so many reducers and the query is running fast.

can anyone please tell me what could be the reason behind this.

Comment: Maybe I'm getting too old, but at first glance I don't see any reason to use a _reduce_ step here -- a simple INSERT-SELECT should just use a _map_ step, with several mappers in parallel. No _shuffle_, no _reduce_.

Comment: Ah, unless there is a configuration about "merge small files for map-only query" that kicks in and forces a pseudo-reduce step.